# Explain sandwich theorem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I was reading my math book trying to understand "limits and derivatives". I understood almost everything till this. Below is the statement from my book. Can anyone please explain this to me.

> If $f(x)\le g(x)$ for every $x$ in the deleted neighbourhood of $a$, $\lim_{x\to a} \hspace{1 mm} f(x) \le \lim_{{x}\to{a}} \hspace{1 mm}g(x)$. If $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x$) for every $x$ in the deleted neighbourhood of $a$ and $\lim_{{x}\to{a}} \hspace{1 mm} f(x) = l = \lim_{{x}\to{a}} \hspace{1 mm} h(x)$ then $\lim_{{x}\to{a}} \hspace{1 mm} g(x) = l$. This result is often stated as Sandwich Theorem.

Please explain what is meant by "for every $x$ in the deleted neighbourhood"? If possible please explain it in the most possible simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ( $f(x) \le g(x)$ for any $x \in I \backslash \{a\}$ ) for some $I$ that is a neighbourhood of $a$:

$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ **if both limits exists**.

If your book is only referring to functions on $\mathbb{R}$, then it may use 'neighbourhood' to simply mean an open interval, in which case a deleted neighbourhood of $a$ would be the same as an open interval containing $a$ except that it excludes $a$. In the case of this theorem, it means that if there is some open interval on which $f$ is not greater than $g$, at most except at $a$ (where $f,g$ do not even have to be defined), then the limits of $f$ and $g$ at $a$ obey the same inequality if both limits exist in the first place.

Note that the above theorem does not apply if either limit does not exist, unlike what the book seems to imply by its statement. This means that before you can use this theorem you must have proven that both limits exist.

The squeeze theorem (or sandwich theorem) says the following:

If ( $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ for any $x \in I \backslash \{a\}$ ) for some $I$ that is a neighbourhood of $a$, and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} h(x) = c$:

$\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = c$.

Note that the squeeze theorem only applies if you know that both $f$ and $h$ have a limit at $a$, and that their limits are equal, and if so it tells you that $g$ has a limit at $a$ and that limit is the same as the other two. So the squeeze theorem does not follow from the earlier theorem. Here is a direct proof of the squeeze theorem:

If ( $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ for any $x \in I$ ) for some $I$ that is a deleted neighbourhood of $a$, and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} h(x) = c$:

For any $ε > 0$:

Let $J$ be a deleted neighbourhood of $a$ such that $f(J) \subseteq (c-ε,c+ε)$.

Let $K$ be a deleted neighbourhood of $a$ such that $h(K) \subseteq (c-ε,c+ε)$.

Let $S = I \cap J \cap K$.

Then $S$ is a deleted neighbourhood of $a$.

Also $f(S) \subseteq f(J) \subseteq (c-ε,c+ε)$.

And $h(S) \subseteq h(K) \subseteq (c-ε,c+ε)$.

For any $x \in S$:

$c-ε < f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x) < c+ε$.

Therefore $g(S) \subseteq (c-ε,c+ε)$

Therefore $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = c$.

Comment: Could you prove the sandwich theorem?

Comment: @pcforgeek: Your book doesn't prove it? I can add it in.

Answer (score 0):

Put another way: Draw two curves that intersect at $x=a$.  Now draw a curve that never goes above the top one or below the bottom.  Try as hard as you can, the new curve is going to intersect the other two at $x=a$

Here's the more mathematical terms:

So a deleted neighborhood is just a small region around $a$ that has $a$ removed (or punched out, you might say).

So I'm not going to say anything about what these things equal at $a$, just what they are for nearby $x$.

The first statement is that if $f(x)\leq g(x)$, everywhere in this region, then whatever they converge to as $x\to a$ has to satisfy this inequality.

Similarly if $g(x) \leq h(x)$ whatever they converge to as $x \to a$ satisfies the inequality.

If the limit of $f$ and $h$ are the same, then gosh, $g$ has to be the same too.